# Create a language package, install a language package via admin?

Tags: magento2, language, language-package

I have a **Magento 2** shop hosted using a traditional `cPanel` hosting solution. Performance seems to be stable with the demo data and I'd like to install a language pack.

My problem is that I can only access a file manager, or run very simple commands by creating one-time **cron jobs** that execute a command ! and I have to manually delete them afterwards.

How can I install a language pack using these restrictions, since I do not believe I have composer installed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your **requirements**, you can create a translation module yourself manually.

1. `app/i18n/languageName/code_ISO/code_ISO.csv`

   **Example:** for the ***French*** language it will be like this: `app/i18n/french/fr_FR/fr_FR.csv`

   - You put your translation words inside `fr_FR.csv`like this :

   `"Hello","Bonjour"`

   - You can specify the translation for some module like this, *example* here is a **captcha module**
     `"Incorrect CAPTCHA","CAPTCHA incorrect",module,Magento_Captcha`
2. `app/i18n/languageName/code_ISO/language.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
       <code>code_ISO</code>
       <vendor>languageName</vendor>
       <package>code_iso</package>
   </language>
   ```

   French language **example**:
   `app/i18n/french/fr_FR/language.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
       <code>fr_FR</code>
       <vendor>french</vendor>
       <package>fr_fr</package>
   </language>
   ```
3. `app/i18n/languageName/code_ISO/registration.php`

   ```
   <?php
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
       'languageName_code_iso',
       __DIR__
   );
   ```

   French language **example**:
   `app/i18n/french/fr_FR/registration.php`

   ```
   <?php
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
       'french_fr_fr',
       __DIR__
       );
   ```
4. Clean your cache, deploy the static-content like this :

   - Delete the contents of `pub/static` except `.htaccess`
   - Delete the contents of `var/cache`
   - Delete the contents of `var/view_preprocessed`
   - Run this command:
     `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Ideally I'd like to be able to use one of the community available language packs. How could I use those language packs and adapt them to make it work with your solution?

Comment: You download the package then you copy the csv language file `code_ISO.csv` in my module, you can after that customising it. Or you install it directly with composer if you can